# Put players position on the scoreboard in bedrock edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been searching for a while trying to figure out how to put a players position onto a scoreboard in Bedrock Edition, but I can only find stuff for Java Edition. I need just the x and z axis. I need this or something similar because I'm trying to play Minecraft man hunt with my friends, and I don't want to have to set the world spawn to make a compass work

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to do this, but depending on what you're doing you could try teleporting armor stands at Y 256 to save locations.

Comment: @Penguin I'm trying to do Minecraft Manhunt with my friends, and so I want to do something like with the scoreboard so I don't have to set the world spawn to make a compass work

Comment: I don't think there's any other good method besides the compass method that I can think of. What you are asking for directly is not possible